# Custom NSCoding object, Swift (map)

Tags: ios, swift

I have this class :

```
class Point: NSCoding {

var x: String?
var y: Double?

override func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.x     <- map["x"]
    self.y     <- map["y"]
}
...
```

In my ViewModel I have a function that generates an array of Double. 
I need to create a var with those Double to the y parameters of Points, and 2 string to the x parameters.

I've done something like this but this was with a Point object so everything fits.

```
let points = PointObject.map { point in
   Point(x: point.x ?? "0", y: point.y ?? 0.0).self
}
```

Any suggestion/help? I'm not very familiar with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two arrays of String/x and Double/y values:

```
let xValues = ["0", "1"]
let yValues = [2.0, 3.0]
```

you can create `Point`s using `zip` and `map`

```
let points = zip(xValues, yValues).map {
    Point(x: $0.0, y: $0.1)
}
```

Comment: I badly explained my self, the last piece of code is working. I need to do the same with an array with 2 string and an array with Double. Lets see "var myVar = [Double]" and myVar is filled with 5/6 value. (Maybe I dont need the same process, I just need a var points with this Point object and my string and array of double.)

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're trying to ask. It sounds like it should be a separate question, not a follow-up in comments here, though.

Comment: I badly explaind myself again. Your piece of code it's working! But if my string array has 3 element and the double array has 8 element, my output is that strings are repeated (and duplicated). I'm asking If there is a mistake or if I'm making a mistake somewhere else

Comment: `zip` would only return 3 tuples in this case (since it can't build more pairs from the two arrays). Again, please post this new problem including your data and code as a separate question.